# Add a column after copy paste and enter value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a column after pasting in a range, and then populate that new column with static data.

What I have seems to be close, the data appears in the sheet, it inserts the new column, until I enter the value "e1". It's entering a value in the entire column, not just the range, and it's replacing column 5 ("E") data instead of entering into the new column 4 ("D")

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Dim SourceData As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationData As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange1 As Range
    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    Dim ShiftRange As Range

    Set SourceData = Sheets("is")
    Set DestinationData = Sheets("reformatted")

    Set SourceRange1 = SourceData.Range("A2", SourceData.Range("F1").End(xlDown))

    Set DestinationRange = DestinationData.Range("A2", DestinationData.Range("G1").End(xlDown))
    Set ShiftRange = DestinationData.Range("D2", DestinationData.Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    ' Run Group 1
    SourceRange1.Copy Destination:=DestinationRange
    ShiftRange.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ShiftRange.Cells.Value = "e1"
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set ShiftRange = DestinationData.Range("D2", DestinationData.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
```

This defines `ShiftRange` to be all the cells in column D, starting at D2 and going down until the last cell prior to an empty cell.

```
ShiftRange.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

This has now inserted a cells to the left of `ShiftRange`, therefore `ShiftRange` is in column E.

```
ShiftRange.Cells.Value = "e1"
```

This sets the value of all the cells in `ShiftRange` (which is in column E) to be "e1".

It won't set **all** the cells in the column to be "e1", just the cells in `ShiftRange`.  However, if all the cells in D3:D1048576 of the destination sheet were empty prior to the copy, then `ShiftRange` will be `D2:D1048576` which will be **nearly all** the cells in the column.

---

I think you want

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Dim SourceData As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationData As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange1 As Range
    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    Dim ShiftRange As Range

    Set SourceData = Sheets("is")
    Set DestinationData = Sheets("reformatted")

    Set SourceRange1 = SourceData.Range("A2", SourceData.Range("F1").End(xlDown))

    Set DestinationRange = DestinationData.Range("A2", DestinationData.Range("G1").End(xlDown))

    ' Run Group 1
    SourceRange1.Copy Destination:=DestinationRange
    'Define ShiftRange after the data has been placed in the destination sheet
    Set ShiftRange = DestinationData.Range("D2", DestinationData.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    'Shift column D to column E
    ShiftRange.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    'Insert values in column D
    ShiftRange.Offset(0, -1).Value = "e1"
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```